# Pandas Dataframe add columns based on existing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 100s of columns and 1000s of rows but the basic structure is

```
Index     0       1       2
0         AAA     NaN     AAA
1         NaN     BBB     NaN
2         NaN     NaN     CCC
3         DDD     DDD     DDD
```

I would like to add two new columns one would be and id which would be equal to the first value in each row the second would be a count of the values in each row. It would look like this. To be clear all rows will always have the same value.

```
Index   id    count     0       1       2
0        AAA     2      AAA     NaN     AAA
1        BBB     1      NaN     BBB     NaN
2        CCC     1      NaN     NaN     CCC
3        DDD     3      DDD     DDD     DDD
```

Any help in figuring out a way to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
df['id'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna('All NANs')
df['count'] = df.drop(columns=["id"]).notnull().sum(axis=1)
```

To maintain the order of columns:

```
df = df[list(df.columns[-2:]) + list(df.columns[:-2])]
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much. I've been pulling my hair out over this all day. I hate to be a pest but is there anyway to do the same thing but have the new columns be the first two?

Comment: Wow that is fantastic! You really are a lifesaver.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Create the Dataframe

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame([['AAA',np.nan,'AAA'], [np.nan,'BBB',np.nan], [np.nan,np.nan, 'CCC'], ['DDD','DDD','DDD']])
```

Count the non-NaN elements in each row as `count`

```
test_df['count'] = test_df.notna().sum(axis=1)
```

**Option-1:** Select the first element in the row as `id` (regardless of NaN value)

```
test_df['id'] = test_df[0]
```

**Option-2:** Select the first non-NaN element as `id` for each row

```
test_df['id'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because the id is supposed to be the first non Nan value in the row.

Comment: @Rohith It says the first value in each row, not the first non-NaN value.

Comment: True! But the sample solution requested by @rwa was the first non-NaN value. The question also says count of values, not count of non-NaN values. But we assumed so by referring to the sample solution

Comment: I see where I made a mistake in my wording. Thank you both for the feedback. I now see how I should have phrased the question. I've just started learning. I'll take all the help I can get.